# python requests not work with vpn ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.',

Tags: python, networking, python-requests, urllib, vpn

I use requests with vpn and it show error

```
(Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError(0, 'Error')))
```

this is code

```
import requests
con = requests.get(url)
```

I can visit url in browser with vpn. I hav to use vpn to requests.
use Python 3.7.9

Answer (score 0):

using pyPAC works for me...
https://pypac.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```
from pypac import PACSession
from requests.auth import HTTPProxyAuth
session = PACSession()
r = session.get('http://google.com')
```

you may need to update your python version or use an older version of pyPAC that matches your python version.